# onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) is not calling

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using this [library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) for pinch zoom .But image Rotate is not working when I am rotating image.It is going to first image.I saw the log file. here activity is restarting at rotate time.

I tried this code :-

```
<activity android:name="imageTouchs" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" />
```

and also

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.imagetouchs);
 System.out.println("configu call " +newConfig);
}
```

But here my `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` is not being called.

Can someone point what can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

replace your configChanges attrib value in xml

from

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

to

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`exported` attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported)